# Session management after implementing openid

Tags: asp.net, session, dotnetopenauth

i have implemented the the openid in my page using dotnet open id when i get authenticated iam storing the details provided by openid provider in my database and creating a session of that username and redirecting the user to login protected page it is working fine but some time if i left the page idle for some time and then do any kind of postback then the session is lost and my page do not allows me to do any thing as it is login protected some time it is working fine without any problem. can you suggest me why is it so.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an OpenID problem at all, but rather just an ASP.NET session timeout issue.  Your timeout is perhaps set too low.  But in general the session will still timeout and catch some people during a POST.  And you'll have to decide how your site wants to deal with that.  ASP.NET will automatically redirect the user to the login page and the POST data will be lost.

One possible way to deal with this is to have a session keep-alive Javascript bit running on the client page while the user is filling out whatever long form you have to post.